# Filtering dataframe column in list-like format using substring

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

I have the following dataframe of person number (unique and non duplicate) and the roles those people have all condensended in a list-like format (for people with more than 1 role) like this:

```
         Person Number                                          Role Name
0          10000170             [HR Business Partner, HR Administrator, HR Administrator Limited]
1          10000479             [HR Administrator, HR Administrator Reporting]
2          10001347             [HR Business Partner, HR Administrator]
3          10003004             [HR Business Partner Approver, HR Business Partner]
4          10003048             [HR Administrator, HR Administrator Reporting]
5          10062441             [HR Business Partner Security Limited, HR Administrator Limited]
6          10062862             [HR Business Partner, HR Business Partner Approver]
7          10063101             HR Business Partner
8          10063833             HR Administrator
```

I would like to filter this dataframe in the following:

1- Return all rows where the "Role Name" column is in a list-like format:

OUTPUT:

```
         Person Number                                          Role Name
0          10000170             [HR Business Partner, HR Administrator, HR Administrator Limited]
1          10000479             [HR Administrator, HR Administrator Reporting]
2          10001347             [HR Business Partner, HR Administrator]
3          10003004             [HR Business Partner Approver, HR Business Partner]
4          10003048             [HR Administrator, HR Administrator Reporting]
5          10062441             [HR Business Partner Security Limited, HR Administrator Limited]
6          10062862             [HR Business Partner, HR Business Partner Approver]
```

2 - Filter this dataframe in a way that return all employee rows where in their "Role Name" value may contain the word "Business Partner" AND the word "Administrator] returning this:

OUTPUT:

```
         Person Number                                          Role Name
0          10000170             [HR Business Partner, HR Administrator, HR Administrator Limited]
2          10001347             [HR Business Partner, HR Administrator]
5          10062441             [HR Business Partner Security Limited, HR Administrator Limited]
```

How could I achieve each of the outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible idea is using a custom function to generate a *boolean mask* from the column `Role Name` by using [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html), finally using this mask to filter the rows in dataframe:

```
def fx(v):
    if not isinstance(v, list):
        return False

    roles = ','.join(v).lower()
    return 'business partner' in roles and 'administrator' in roles

df1 = df[df['Role Name'].apply(fx)]
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
  Person Number                                          Role Name
0      10000170  [HR Business Partner,  HR Administrator,  HR A...
2      10001347           [HR Business Partner,  HR Administrator]
5      10062441  [HR Business Partner Security Limited,  HR Adm...
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it is returning an empty dataframe for me

Comment: @PauloCortez As per the data provided by you in the example, this is working for me.? Are the rows in the `Role Name` column instances of `list` or are they simple strings surrounded by `[]`?

Comment: I grouped all elements in a list for each unique "Role" in the Person Number. So I believe some are lists, some are strings? As some Person Number only have 1 role, so it was not grouped into a list @ShubhamSharma

Comment: #Write Function:
def f(x):
     L = list(set(y for y in x if pd.notna(y)))
     #if empty list return NaN
     if len(L) == 0:
         return np.nan
     #if one element list return scalar
     elif len(L) == 1:
         return L[0]
     #else return full list
     else:
         return L

Comment: @PauloCortez Is the code given above working on sample data in the question provided by you?

Comment: No, it returns an empty dataframe in the sample data provided extracted from that dataframe

Comment: can you show the output of `type(df['Role Name'].iloc[0])`?

Comment: I checked and the values between "[ ]" are from the type "list" and values outside "[ ]" are from type "str"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217200/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-paulo-cortez).